# How to set BottomNavigationView letterSpacing?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

In TextView, I can use `android:letterSpacing="0.1"` to set letter spacing

But this is not work in BottomNavigationView

I use this code to set font style of BottomNavigationView

I guess I can also set letter spacing here, but I cannot find related method

How to set the letter spacing?

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" >

val font = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "UniversNextPro-LightCond.otf")
val typefaceSpan = CustomTypefaceSpan("", font)
navigation.menu.size()
for (i in 0 until navigation.menu.size()) {
    val menuItem = navigation.menu.getItem(i)
    val spannableTitle = SpannableStringBuilder(menuItem.getTitle())
    spannableTitle.setSpan(typefaceSpan, 0, spannableTitle.length, 0)
    menuItem.setTitle(spannableTitle)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it in this way:

1. Create a style where the parent is `Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView`

```
<style name="BottomNavigationTheme" parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.1</item>
</style>
```

2. Set the style as theme of your Bottom Navigation View

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" >
```